# C++ compiles but gives error when executed

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I am new to Linux Ubuntu 11.10 and have basic C++exposure.

I installed the g++ by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and created a directory cpp in my home directory. I then wrote a program hello.cpp in my cpp directory

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello !" ; return 0;
}
```

and compiled using

```
g++ -W hello.cpp -o hello
```

The program compiles without any errors/warnings. When I try to execute the file

```
./hello.cpp
```

I get error messages:

```
line 3: using: command not found
line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 6: `int main() {'
```

I tried looking at a lot of posts but could not resolve this. I have MS VisualStudio on Windows, but I would rather learn C++ on Ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to execute the .cpp source file rather than the generated executable.  Try running `./hello` instead of `./hello.cpp`, since `hello` is the actual executable.  The errors you're currently getting are caused by the shell interpreter choking on C++ syntax, since it's trying to run it as a shell script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked.I really feel stupid..clearly I have a long way to go..

Comment: @user1178883- No worries, and don't feel stupid!  You have a really exciting journey up ahead of you.  Don't sweat the small stuff. :-)

Comment: @user1178883: Yeah, don't worry. Everybody bumpes against things like that all the time. The only thing you can do is say "Duh!". :-)