# Running c++ file with raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I was making a simple hello world c++ program. For some reason, it won't run after I compile it. Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello world";
}
```

I compiled using:

```
g++ -std=c++0x helloworld.cpp
```

No errors. However, when I tried running it using ./helloworld.cpp, I got this:

```
./helloworld.cpp: line 2: using: command not found
./helloworld.cpp: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./helloworld.cpp: line 5: `int main()'
```

Of course, I tried looking this up, and found a link that had someone asking almost the exact same question as mine. ([C++ compiles but gives error when executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070110/c-compiles-but-gives-error-when-executed)). They told me to remove the .cpp. However, I tried doing ./helloworld and I still got errors. It told me this:

```
bash: helloworld: No such file or directory
```

Also, I was in the directory with helloworld.cpp in it, so I don't think that was the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot run a c++ source from the shell. You compile an executable and run that one.

Comment: Oh. I was wondering what a.out was. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g++ -std=c++0x helloworld.cpp
```

should have left you with an `a.out` file that you can execute.

> However, when I tried running it using ./helloworld.cpp, I got this:
>   ...

You can't execute the `helloworld.cpp` source from the shell.

---

You probably should use

```
g++ -std=c++0x helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
                            # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to name the executable file other than `a.out`

You can call `./helloworld` then to run your compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a .cpp file. Find where the compiled program is and run that.

Answer (score 0):

The .cpp file is the file you wrote. It's a text file, so you obviously can't  "run" it. If you build a program you create an executable, which you can execute. This is a different file.